# Problem connecting to SFTP using Paramiko

Tags: python, python-3.x, sftp, paramiko

This is the snippet of the code I have been using to connect to an SFTP to pull files. It's a basic sftp connection using paramiko in Python.

```
def get_fund_files():
    host, port = "ftp.example.com", 22
    transport = paramiko.Transport((host, port))
    # Auth
    username, password = "user", "password"
    transport.connect(None, username, password)
    # Go!
    with paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport) as sftp:
```

The problem now is that the code all the sudden stopped working on my Bitnami ubunto server. And I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 288, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 15, in main
    get_fund_files()
  File "main.py", line 28, in get_fund_files
    transport.connect(None, username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1263, in connect
    self.auth_password(username, password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1431, in auth_password
    self.auth_handler.auth_password(username, password, my_event)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 138, in auth_passwo
rd
    self._request_auth()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/auth_handler.py", line 189, in _request_au
th
    self.transport._send_message(m)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1766, in _send_message
    self.packetizer.send_message(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko/packet.py", line 399, in send_message
    out = self.__block_engine_out.update(packet)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/ciphers/base.py", li
ne 149, in update
    return self._ctx.update(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py", l
ine 124, in update
    n = self.update_into(data, buf)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/ciphers.py", l
ine 140, in update_into
   ** self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(data, require_writable=True), len(data)
BufferError: Object is not writable.**
```

The weird part is that I tried running the same code on a clone instance and it runs fine. So I'm not sure if the problem is the code or the server. I was hoping anyone could help me make sense of this. Nothing has changed in the server or sftp that I know of. From my tests, the problem happens at `transport.connect(None, username, password)`. But I'm not sure how to deal with this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,

The code pulls files from an SFTP server. It was working fine until today. Nothing really changed that I know of.

Comment: Well, searching online for the error message brought [this post up](https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/5dBZGGXs8xU) that more or less describe the exact issue - someone or something may have updated the system package `python3-cryptography` (as that's where the import was from, `/usr/lib/python3`).  See if you can either downgrade the package and/or set up a virtualenv and install the relevant packages and see if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks metatoaster for the hint. All I needed to do was upgrade cryptography and it was working again.

```
pip3 install --upgrade cryptography
```